# Create config Java script file with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, json, validation, dynamic

I have a config file as shown below

```
import { small,vario,large } from "./../../configs/response.constants";
export const barChartColorConfig = {
  [small]:"rgb(149, 206, 255)",
  [vario]:"rgb(92, 92, 97)",
  [large]:"rgb(166, 253, 147)"
};
```

It is a Js file where key (small,vario,large) are dynamic string values coming from response.constants file

```
export const small="small";
export const vario="vario";
export const large='large';
```

when i tried to put in JSON validation online it say invalid

Is there a way to write  [small] in some other way in the config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON validator you're using may not correctly recognize [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), which are supported in ES5.

Comment: Can u please point to any JSON validator which supports in ES5

Comment: @DhanaLaxshmi JavaScript syntax is not JSON syntax, which is why the validator is failing. Since you're using computed property names, an ES5 parser wouldn't understand your code either. But it's 2022 - don't be afraid to use at least ES2015 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not the same as JavaScript. Although you can create strings containing proper JSON-formatted strings inside of JavaScript, they're distinct concepts. Here:

```
export const barChartColorConfig = {
  [small]:"rgb(149, 206, 255)",
  [vario]:"rgb(92, 92, 97)",
  [large]:"rgb(166, 253, 147)"
};
```

You're creating a plain JavaScript object. It's not JSON. If you tried to validate the content of the object as JSON, it would fail - because it's JavaScript syntax and not a JSON string.

If you stringified the object after its creation and tried to validate it, you'd get:

```js
const small = "small";
const vario = "vario";
const large = 'large';
const barChartColorConfig = {
  [small]: "rgb(149, 206, 255)",
  [vario]: "rgb(92, 92, 97)",
  [large]: "rgb(166, 253, 147)"
};

const json = JSON.stringify(barChartColorConfig);
console.log(json);
```

`{"small":"rgb(149, 206, 255)","vario":"rgb(92, 92, 97)","large":"rgb(166, 253, 147)"}`, which *is* valid JSON.

So even if a JSON formatter says that your JavaScript markup with bracket notation is invalid JSON, that's completely normal and expected. You aren't doing anything wrong.